# Tracing Rails 3 SQL queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, stack-trace

Is there any gem which works on Rails 3 that can show **which part of my code generated which SQL query**?

On Rails 2.3 there was plugin called [query_trace](https://github.com/ntalbott/query_trace), but it doesn't seem to work on Rails 3, it generates following error:

```
alias_method': undefined method `log_info' for class `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractAdapter' (NameError)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

QueryTrace doesn't work as-is because many changes were made in Rails 3 esp in the area of ActiveRecord.

So, hacking around, I made it work like this:

You just need the 2 files below in the locations mentioned. Then restart the web server.
After the SQL, you should see `Called from:` in a console (magenta on white) and log file

In `/vendor/plugins/query_trace/lib/query_trace.rb`

```
module QueryTrace
  def self.append_features(klass)
    super
    klass.class_eval do
      unless method_defined?(:log_info_without_trace)
        alias_method :log_info_without_trace, :sql
        alias_method :sql, :log_info_with_trace
      end
    end
  end

  def log_info_with_trace(event)
    log_info_without_trace(event)
    logger.debug("\e[1m\e[35m\e[1m\e[47mCalled from:\e[0m " + clean_trace(caller[2..-2]).join("\n "))
  end

  def clean_trace(trace)
    Rails.respond_to?(:backtrace_cleaner) ?
      Rails.backtrace_cleaner.clean(trace) :
      trace
  end
end
```

In `/vendor/plugins/query_trace/init.rb`

```
require 'query_trace'

class ::ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber
  include QueryTrace
end
```

Comment: Great solution. I would add "if Rails.env.development?" in the init.rb file.

Answer (score 7):

https://github.com/lightyear/sql-logging

Comment: This appears to be a rewrite of query_trace for rails3. At least, the credits acknowledge the original query_trace.

Comment: Had really good results with this gem. Not color-coded but the depth and accuracy of the stack trace is excellent.

Answer (score 5):

A port of query_trace to rails3

https://gist.github.com/1137342

Answer (score 1):

The [active_record_query_trace](https://github.com/brunofacca/active-record-query-trace) also does that.

1. Add the following to your Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'active_record_query_trace'
end
```

2. Create an initializer such as `config/initializers/active_record_query_trace.rb` to enable the gem. If you want to customize how the gem behaves, you can add any combination of the options described in the [docs](https://github.com/brunofacca/active-record-query-trace) to the initializer as well.

```
if Rails.env.development?
 ActiveRecordQueryTrace.enabled = true
 # Optional: other gem config options go here
end
```

3. Restart the Rails development server.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a good fork here:

https://github.com/dolzenko/query_trace

Note that the QUERY_TRACE constant in the documentation doesn't seem to work, but the QueryTrace.enable! does (must be in an initializer, I tried putting it into config/development.rb first)

Comment: that gave me a "wrong number of arguments" backtrace, so I don't think it is working for rails 3.2 at least