# how to print the executing sql from Active record in rails 2

Tags: sql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

I would like to print into log or console the executing sql. Where can I make some settings? In hibernate it is in a config file possibility: I think here should be something like that too.

I have a code part similar to this:

```
myresult = MyActiveRecordClass.find(:all, :select => "mytable1.*, mytable2.field1", :joins => :mytable2, :conditions => "somefield= #{somefield}", :order => "another_field desc", :offset => offset, :limit => limit)
```

This is a simpler case to translate by hand, but I would like to have all the native sql in a console or in file. It could be usefully at searching

Answer (score 1):

Rails already displays the SQL in the development log and console (at `debug` log level - so ensure that the logger is able to display `debug` log messages).

To also display where in the source code a SQL was called from:

Rails 2: [query_trace](https://github.com/ntalbott/query_trace) plugin

Rails 3: [Tracing Rails 3 SQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530870/tracing-rails-3-sql-queries/4531494#4531494) (based on query_trace, but works for Rails 3 because query_trace does not currently work on Rails 3)