# Determining location of SQL Statement in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In development mode, I can see SQL statements in the `rails server` logs. How can I determine what is creating those SQL statements?

Comment: I look for the controller action that precedes them. It should post whether its a `put`, `post` and `get` request.. and what action performed the request.

Comment: Similar question for Rails 3 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530870/tracing-rails-3-sql-queries

Answer (score 0):

Try `active_record_query_trace` gem.

See https://github.com/brunofacca/active-record-query-trace